# how how iloc[:,1:] works ? can any one explain [:,1:] params

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sklearn-pandas

What is the meaning of below lines., especially confused about how iloc[:,1:] is working ? and also data[:,:1]

```
data = np.asarray(train_df_mv_norm.iloc[:,1:])
X, Y = data[:,1:],data[:,:1]
```

Here train_df_mv_norm is a dataframe --

[image: one]

Answer (score 8):

Definition: [pandas iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

> .iloc[] is primarily integer position based (from 0 to length-1 of the
>   axis), but may also be used with a boolean array.

For example:

```
df.iloc[:3] # slice your object, i.e. first three rows of your dataframe
df.iloc[0:3] # same
df.iloc[0, 1] # index both axis. Select the element from the first row, second column.
df.iloc[:, 0:5] # first five columns of data frame with all rows
```

So, your dataframe `train_df_mv_norm.iloc[:,1:]` will select all rows but your first column will be excluded.

Note that:

- `df.iloc[:,:1]` select all rows and columns from 0 (included) to 1 (excluded).
- `df.iloc[:,1:]` select all rows and columns, but exclude column 1.

Comment: ok thank you, so data[:,:1] will be selecting on (all rows, and first row will be excluded ) right ?

Comment: Almost, I have completed my answer

Answer (score 3):

To complete the answer by *KeyMaker00*, I add that `data[:,:1]` means:

- The first `:` - take all rows.
- `:1` - equal to `0:1` take columns starting from column *0*,
  up to (**excluding**) column *1*.

So, to sum up, the second expression reads only the **first column** from *data*.

As your expression has the form:

```
<variable_list> = <expression_list>
```

each expression is substituted under the corresponding variable (*X* and *Y*).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it will complete the answers before.
You will know

1. what you get,
2. its shape
3. how to use it with de column name

```py
    df.iloc[:,1:2]        # get column 1 as a DATAFRAME of shape (n, 1) 
    df.iloc[:,1:2].values # get column 1 as an NDARRAY of shape (n, 1)
    df.iloc[:,1].values   # get column 1 as an NDARRAY of shape ( n,) 
    df.iloc[:,1]          # get column 1 as a SERIES of shape (n,) 
    # iloc with the name of a column 
    df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_loc('my_col')] # maybe there is some more
```

elegants methods