# Average of specific rows and columns using loc[] in Pandas

Tags: pandas, multiple-columns, rows, mean, pandas-loc

Here I am trying to pull average of rows 0 through 8 and columns "9/15/2020" through "9/18/2020" from df dataframe using .loc[] in pandas

[This is the df dataframe having 8 rows and 9 columns][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgjBp.png

Have tried using following long syntax : This works fine
**Average = df.loc[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] ,['15-Sep-20','16-Sep-20','17-Sep-20','18-Sep-20']].mean(axis=1)**

But when using the following shorter code it throws syntax error:
**Average_compact= df.loc[[0:8] ,['15-Sep-20':'18-Sep-20']]).mean(axis=1)**

output:
File "", line 1

```
Average_compact= df.loc[[0:8] ,['15-Sep-20':'18-Sep-20']].mean(axis=1)
                          ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Where am i doing wrong ?
Also how can i select the entire range of available rows i.e from 0 to last row without mentioning the end row number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try using iloc instead of loc:

```
df[column_list].iloc[row_index_list].mean(axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks , but here too I need to enter the entire set of columns and rows manually which I am avoiding as data set may be bigger than this ..so i need a syntax that specifies a range . Using loc[] its not accepting ":" for range

Comment: but iloc accepts ":" , try [0, :] to select all..also this might help you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56311638/how-how-iloc-1-works-can-any-one-explain-1-params